# Registrar datos unicos segun una fecha unica

Tags: php, html, laravel

He revisado mil publicaciones en foros y aun no consigo solucion.
Tengo un tabla de registros, donde se pueden registrar fechas y turnos(donde este puede ser 1, 2 o 3). Pero lo que intento hacer es que exista un registro unico de turno 1, 2 y 3 de cada fecha.
Ejemplo:
Del dia 11 de Noviembre de 2021, solo puede existir un registro unico con un turno 1, un turno 2, y un turno 3.

Intente implementar el metodo unique(), pero me lanzan errores de base de datos. Quizas este haciendolo mal

Adjunto codigos de controlador

**RegistroController.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $registros = new Registro();
        $fecha =  $registros -> fecha;

        $v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            
            'fecha' => 'required',
            'turno'    => 'required|unique:registros,fecha',
            'vagones_teu' => 'required',
            'grs_89' => 'required',
            'tolva_fino' => 'required',
            'tolva_grs' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($v->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($v->errors());
        }

        $registros -> fecha = $request -> get("fecha");
        $registros -> turno = $request -> get("turno");
        $registros -> vagones_teu = $request -> get("vagones_teu");
        $registros -> grs_89 = $request -> get("grs_89");
        $registros -> tolva_fino = $request -> get("tolva_fino");
        $registros -> tolva_grs = $request -> get("tolva_grs");

        $registros -> save ();

        return redirect ('/registros');

    }
```

**Aca esta la parte del form**

```
     @if ($errors->any())
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
      @endif

      <form action="/registros" method = "POST">
      @csrf
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row col-12">
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Fecha</label>
              <input type="date"
                class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha" aria-describedby="helpId">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Turno">Turno</label>
              <select class="form-control form-control-user" name="turno" id="turno" placeholder="Seleccione">
                <option id="turno1">1</option>
                <option id="turno2">2</option>
                <option id="turno3">3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>
```

**Migracion de la tabla**

```
        Schema::create('registros', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->dateTime('fecha') -> required();
            $table->integer('turno')-> required();
            $table->integer('vagones_teu')-> required();
            $table->integer('grs_89')-> required();
            $table->integer('tolva_fino')-> required();
            $table->integer('tolva_grs')-> required();
            $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: Con índice único se va a generar un error cuando quieras crear un registro con una clave existente, es el comportamiento normal. Antes de insertar, ejecuta una consulta para ver que no existe fecha + turno y, [_"por si las moscas"_](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-por-si-las-moscas/), agrega manejo de excepciones para, en ambos casos, devolver un mensaje de error: "El turno # ya existe en esa fecha".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, lo que necesitas es *consultar la base de datos para chequear si ya existe algún registro con la fecha y el turno que llegan en el request, y en el caso de que eso sea verdadero, no permitir que avance el request*.

Esa consulta a BD, resultaría bastante simple usando cláusulas `where` y el método [exists()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist):

```
Registro::where('fecha', $request->fecha)
    ->where('turno', $request->turno)
    ->exists();
```

Entonces, a eso lo puedes hacer en la validación del request, creando una [Regla de Validación Personalizada](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Si sólo necesitas la funcionalidad de una regla personalizada una vez en su aplicación, puedes usar un [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures). El closure recibe el nombre del atributo, el valor del atributo y una devolución de llamada `$fail` que se debe llamar si falla la validación:

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'fecha' => 'required',
    'turno' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $exists = Registro::where('fecha', request('fecha'))
                ->where('turno', request('turno'))
                ->exists();
            if ($exists) {
                $fail('El tipo de turno seleccionado no está diponible para la fecha seleccionada.');
            }
        },
    ],
    // otras validaciones
]);
```

Si planeas usar la regla en más de un lugar de tu aplicación, puedes crear una clase que implemente Rule, y hacer la validación [usando objetos de regla](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects).
La lógica de la regla sería la misma, consultar la existencia de un registro.

---

*Nota aparte*: Como programador, con lo anterior me aseguro de que la aplicación cumpla con las reglas de negocio, pero como usuario no me gustaría que la aplicación me deje seleccionar una fecha y turno que después me va a rechazar, sino que directamente me deje seleccionar entre las fechas y turnos disponibles. Pero ese es otro tema más de frontend que depende de ti si quieres implementar.

Comment: Hola, ya implementare el idea que colocaste, para probarla. Gracias. Como tal, mi idea principal era, hacer desaparecer cada turno, conforme a cada registro que ya existiese por cada fecha, para que el usuario no se llevara el mensaje de error. Busque bastante, y creo que tenia que combinar una funcion de js con codigo php para lograrlo. Lo intente, pero me salian algunos errores.

Comment: @Sodi. Vale. Sí, eso sólo fué una idea aparte, que como ya te diste cuenta, necesitarías de js. Pero es otro tema y otro lenguaje que creo que ameritaría que abras otra pregunta con las etiquetas y la información correspondiente a eso.

Comment: Si, me funciona perfecto. Un millon de gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Sodi lo solucionas Unique y check te envio un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #tabla(
id int NOT NULL,
fecha date NOT NULL,
turno int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
UNIQUE (fecha,turno),
check (turno>0 and turno<=3)
)

INSERT INTO #tabla VALUES(1,getdate()-1,1);
INSERT INTO #tabla VALUES(2,getdate()-1,2);
INSERT INTO #tabla VALUES(3,getdate()-1,3);
INSERT INTO #tabla VALUES(4,getdate(),1);

-- ERROR PORQUE YA EXISTE PARA EL DIA DE HOY EL TURNO 1
INSERT INTO #tabla VALUES(5,getdate(),1);

SELECT * FROM #tabla
```

El unique te restringe que solo exista una unica combinacion de esos dos datos, fecha y turno mientras que el check te restringe que el turno no sea mayor que 3 ya que solo tienes 3 turnos.

Espero te sea de ayuda saludos.