# Validacion livewire

Tags: laravel

Buen día, como puedo validar dos campos que sean unicos, es decir mi tabla (well_down_times) esta compuesta por los siguientes campos

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'well_id',
        'fecha',
        'horas', 
        'well_cause_id',
        'agua_perdido_mt3',
        'oil_perdido_mt3',
        'gas_perdido_mt3',
        'obs',
        'estado'

    ];
```

Cuando creo un registro debe validarme que la fecha y well_id no pueden ser iguales, puedo tener fecha=16/12/2021 - well_id=1, fecha 16/12/2021, well_id=2, pero no puedo tener :
fecha=16/12/2021 - well_id=1, fecha 16/12/2021, well_id=1

mis reglas

```
  protected function getRules(){   
        if( $this->action == "updateWelldowntime"){
            $rules = [
                'welldowntime.fecha' => 'required|min:10|max:10|unique:well_down_times,fecha,' .$this->welldowntimeId,
            ];
        }else{
            $rules = [
                'welldowntime.fecha' => 'required|min:10|max:10|unique:well_down_times,fecha,well_id',
  
            ];

        }
        return array_merge([
            'welldowntime.well_id' => 'required',
            'welldowntime.horas' => 'required',
            'welldowntime.well_cause_id' => 'required',
            'welldowntime.agua_perdido_mt3' => 'required',
            'welldowntime.oil_perdido_mt3' => 'required',
            'welldowntime.gas_perdido_mt3' => 'required',

        ], $rules);

    }
```

Comment: Buen día, en el ejemplo que compartes `well_id` es único pero la fecha puede repetirse, entonces basta con que `well_id` lo definas como único y la fecha sería solo requerido. Podrías describir un poco más el comportamiento que deseas?

Comment: Tengo por ejemplo 50 pozos (well_id) puedo hacer controles de esos pozos las veces que quiera pero no con una misma fecha la fecha no puede repetirse para un mismo pozo

Comment: Lo veo parecido a esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/498994/registrar-datos-unicos-segun-una-fecha-unica/499056 . sólo tendrías que adaptarlo a tus requerimientos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Registrar datos unicos segun una fecha unica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/498994/registrar-datos-unicos-segun-una-fecha-unica)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

La validación de una combinación de columnas que sea única es una función que está disponible a partir de Laravel 5.0 en adelante

La validación funciona de lasiguiente forma:

```
'elemento'  => 'unique:tabla,columna,excepcion,idColumna'
```

Y puedes agregarle condiciones para hacer un `where()`

En tu caso podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
'welldowntime.fecha'  => 'unique:well_down_times,fecha,NULL,NULL,well_id,'. $this->well_id
```

Esto quiere decir que el valor de `welldowntime.fecha` sea único en la tabla `well_down_times` en la columna `fecha` pero que compare únicamente las filas donde la columna `well_id` sea igual a lo que contenga `$this->well_id`

Ya que si `well_id` es diferente puedes utilizar la misma fecha para otra entrada